# Create new text boxes with uniqe names in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I’m trying to create new blank text boxes on demand, while keeping the text entered into the previous  box,  have each box with a unique name, in JavaScript. I been at it for a few hours, got frustrated, and used PHP to do it. But as you know, this creates a call back to the server for every box. What I’m looking to do is convert the following into JavaScript. (FYI: also using jQuery)

index.html

```
<script type="text/jscript">
 function adddefinition() {
  $.post('definitions.php',
   $('form[name="help"]').serialize(),
 function (output) {
    $('#definitions').html(output).show();
    });
    }
</script>

<form name="help" method="post" action="submitnewhelp.php">

Title: <input name="Title" id="t1" type="text">
<br>
<br>
Summary
<textarea name="Summary" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
<hr>
<div id="definitions"></div>
<input name="TD" type="button" value="Add Term and Definition" onclick="adddefinition();">
<hr>
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

definitions.php

```
<?php
for ($Number = 1; !empty($_POST['Term:'.$Number]); $Number++) {}

echo '<input name="TermCount" type="hidden" value='.$Number.'>';

if(!empty($Number)){$TermNumber = $Number;}else{$TermNumber = 1;}
foreach (range(1, $Number) as $number) {
echo 'Term: <input name="Term:'.$number.'" type="text" value="';if(!empty($_POST['Term:'.$number])){echo $_POST['Term:'.$number];}
echo '" style="width: 100px"> Definition:&nbsp; <input name="Definition:'.$number.'" type="text" value="';if(!empty($_POST['Definition:'.$number])){echo $_POST['Definition:'.$number];}
echo '" style="width: 1000px">
<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: James are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqyEPZ

Comment: Your number one task should be to indent your code properly. Otherwise it is very hard to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naga Sai A pointed me in the right direction. The finished jQuery...

```
<script type="text/jscript">
num = 0;
function adddefinition() {
num++;
$('#definitions').append('Term:&nbsp;<input name="Term:'+num+'" type="text">Definition:&nbsp;<input name="Definition:'+num+'" type="text"><br><br>');//Code must be one line//
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to get unique name for your each text boxes.

HTML:

```
 Title: <input name="Title" id="t1" type="text">
<br>
<br> Summary
<textarea name="Summary" cols="20" rows="2" id='test'></textarea>
<hr>
<div id="definitions"></div>
<button onclick="adddefinition()">Add Term and Definition</button>
<hr>
```

Javascript:

```
function adddefinition() {
   if($('.dynamicInput').length>0) {
     elementName = $('.dynamicInput').last().attr('name');
     name = parseInt(elementName.split("_")[1])+1;
     $('<input type="text" name ="test_'+name+'" class="dynamicInput"></br></br>').insertBefore("button");
   } else {
           $('<input type="text" name ="test_1" class="dynamicInput"></br></br>').insertBefore("button");
   }
 };
```

Explanation:

In Jquery, first I have checked whether any element exist with the class name "dynamicInput".

If anything exist with this class name, then I get the name of the last element. And I find the last element's number using the split function. Then I incremented this value to set the unique name for next input box.

If no input box exist with the class name "dynamicInput", then create a new input field with the name "test_1".

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you did

Comment: I have added it in answer itself.